# UnsupportedOperationException: Unsupported format for this image

Tags: java, lwjgl, png

So.. I'm learning lwjgl currently and I stumbled on this weird error caused by slick-util which seems to be incorrectly displayed.

ERROR :

```
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Unsupported format for this image
at org.newdawn.slick.opengl.PNGDecoder.decode(PNGDecoder.java:272)
at org.newdawn.slick.opengl.PNGImageData.loadImage(PNGImageData.java:97)
at org.newdawn.slick.opengl.CompositeImageData.loadImage (CompositeImageData.java:62)                       
at org.newdawn.slick.opengl.CompositeImageData.loadImage(CompositeImageData.java:43)
at org.newdawn.slick.opengl.InternalTextureLoader.getTexture(InternalTextureLoader.java:292)
at org.newdawn.slick.opengl.InternalTextureLoader.getTexture(InternalTextureLoader.java:254)
at org.newdawn.slick.opengl.InternalTextureLoader.getTexture(InternalTextureLoader.
java:200)
at org.newdawn.slick.opengl.TextureLoader.getTexture(TextureLoader.java:64)
at org.newdawn.slick.opengl.TextureLoader.getTexture(TextureLoader.java:24)
at com.saumi.utils.Renderer.loadTexture(Renderer.java:91)
at com.saumi.assets.Assets.<init>(Assets.java:23)
at com.saumi.main.Main.init(Main.java:27)
at com.saumi.main.Main.<init>(Main.java:45)
at com.saumi.main.Main.main(Main.java:71)
```

The problem is that even though it says unable to read png data, the picture that the error points to is loaded properly and even displayed onto the screen!

I don't know what is is supposed to mean, please help.

EDIT :

My texture loader code :

```
public static Texture loadTexture(String path , String fileType){
    Texture tex = null;

    InputStream in = ResourceLoader.getResourceAsStream(path);
    try {
        tex = TextureLoader.getTexture(fileType,in);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return tex;
}
```

My Assets code which loads the textures :

```
public class Assets {

public static Texture playBtn , tutBtn , quitBtn;

public static Texture background;

public static Texture player , missile;

public Assets(){
    playBtn = Renderer.loadTexture("res/PlayBtn.png", "PNG");
    tutBtn = Renderer.loadTexture("res/TutBtn.png", "PNG");
    quitBtn = Renderer.loadTexture("res/QuitBtn.png", "PNG");

    player = Renderer.loadTexture("res/KillSkull.png", "PNG");
    missile = Renderer.loadTexture("res/Missile.png", "PNG");

    background = Renderer.loadTexture("res/Background.png", "PNG");
}

}
```

The Error points to the Background Image , and the order in which it is loaded does not matter, it always points to that image.

Comment: Welcome to GDSE. Your error is formatted as code, so that's fine. It might help us to see a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example (MCVE)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of the problematic code.

Comment: Are you trying to read png data from more than one file or source?

Comment: I've edited the post to show my code, and i am loading the image from a file in my res folder.

Comment: Try substituting one of the other image filenames for `Background.png`. If that works, then you've narrowed the problem to the image file itself. If that doesn't work, then it suggests something else is wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few solutions to this. Try them until you find one that works for you!

### Re-saving the image (Maybe Windows only)

1. Open the image in your image editing program / re-create the image from scratch.
2. Copy the entire image to your clipboard **from your image editing software** (don't save it).
3. Paste the image into MS Paint (**might** work with other programs. Tested only with MS Paint) and save the image as a **.png**.

### Change bit-depth to 32 bit ([credit to Lemonzap](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26941179/5615635))

1. Open your image in your image editing software.
2. Change the bit-depth to 32-bit.

   1. **Paint.net**: You chance it in the save dialog
   2. **Gimp**: Should automatically have 32-bit depth if your `Image > Mode` is RGB.
   3. **Photoshop:** In the menu `Image > Module` choose `32 Bits/Channel` or set it when you create the image ([Image from Zidane](https://ketnoinhau.wordpress.com/2015/03/04/photoshop-how-to-save-files-as-a-png-in-photoshop-cs6/)) 
       [image: photoshop 32-bit]
3. Save like normal.

### Set interlacing to none ([credit to Paulywog](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11620119/5615635))

1. Open your image in your image editing software
2. Change interlacing to none.

   2. **Photoshop**: You change it in the save dialog.
   3. **Gimp:** 
      [image: gimp how to disable interlacing]
3. Save like normal.